My brake pedal goes to the floor when I start my ford duallie
My brake pedal goes to the floor when I start the engine but before that started while driving and I hit my brakes hard or fast the pedal would stop then there's was a pop then the pedal would be stuck to the floor and would have to be pried up before the brakes will release

Those symptoms are the classic signs of a bad master brake cylinder.  You may also have leaking brake fluid somewhere, causing air to enter the system.
